# Is it decorous to refer to mainstays (people recurring in a legal document) by abbreviations?

Tags: england-and-wales, legal-writing

Presume that these mainstays (even if their names are short) can all be [named publicly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Doe).

I fancy referring to them only with my abbreviations that I introduce on the first page, to save space and avoid typos, like for long surnames.

E.g., I'd state (on the first page), before solely using thereafter, my abbreviations of the 4 counterparties (presume this) as: JK for [Leoš Janáček](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leo%C5%A1_Jan%C3%A1%C4%8Dek) (not LJ; this already means Lord Justice of Appeal), ZK for [Zoltán Kodály](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zolt%C3%A1n_Kod%C3%A1ly), GK for [György Kurtág](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gy%C3%B6rgy_Kurt%C3%A1g), and BM for [Bohuslav Martinů](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohuslav_Martin%C5%AF).

Answer (score 3):

No. In formal writing, you refer to people by name. After you use their full name you can just use their last name in future references, but you don't refer to them by their initials. Even in informal writing, you normally don't use initials unless the person is commonly known by their initials (e.g. JFK) or unless you're using shorthand.

Comment: In family law and probate cases where many people have the same surname, it is acceptable to note a full name in a first instance and then to use a first name thereafter if you expressly note in a footnote that you are doing so to avoid confusion. But, again, not abbreviations.